# Gradle + Netbeans

Tags: java, android, netbeans

I'm trying to open an android project using NetBeans portable (8.0), but I keep getting this error message "Failed to load gradle project". I have gradle plugin installed and I'm on win7. 
This is my stacktrace:

```
 Issue 1
--------

  Requested project: C:\Users\nlstudent\Desktop\giraff-android-master

  Stack trace:
    org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip'.
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory$ZippedDistribution$1.call(DistributionFactory.java:124)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory$ZippedDistribution$1.call(DistributionFactory.java:112)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultModelBuilder.get(DefaultModelBuilder.java:48)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.model.GradleModelLoader.loadModelWithProgress(GradleModelLoader.java:495)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.model.GradleModelLoader.access$600(GradleModelLoader.java:63)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.model.GradleModelLoader$6.run(GradleModelLoader.java:372)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.GradleDaemonManager.runNonBlockingGradleTask(GradleDaemonManager.java:36)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.GradleDaemonManager.access$100(GradleDaemonManager.java:23)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.GradleDaemonManager$2.execute(GradleDaemonManager.java:126)
        at org.jtrim.concurrent.AbstractTaskExecutorService$FunctionWrapper.execute(AbstractTaskExecutorService.java:270)
        at org.jtrim.concurrent.AbstractTaskExecutorService$TaskOfAbstractExecutor.execute(AbstractTaskExecutorService.java:340)
        at org.jtrim.concurrent.Tasks$RunOnceCancelableTask.execute(Tasks.java:342)
        at org.jtrim.concurrent.SingleThreadedExecutor$QueuedItem.runTask(SingleThreadedExecutor.java:905)
        at org.jtrim.concurrent.SingleThreadedExecutor$QueuedItem.access$1200(SingleThreadedExecutor.java:884)
        at org.jtrim.concurrent.SingleThreadedExecutor$Impl$Worker.executeTask(SingleThreadedExecutor.java:798)
        at org.jtrim.concurrent.SingleThreadedExecutor$Impl$Worker.processQueue(SingleThreadedExecutor.java:813)
        at org.jtrim.concurrent.SingleThreadedExecutor$Impl$Worker.run(SingleThreadedExecutor.java:847)
        at org.jtrim.concurrent.SingleThreadedExecutor$Impl$1.run(SingleThreadedExecutor.java:453)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1900)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1858)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1841)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1362)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:515)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1300)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:56)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:42)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory$ProgressReportingDownload.download(DistributionFactory.java:173)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:57)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:44)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:44)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory$ZippedDistribution$1.call(DistributionFactory.java:118)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory$ZippedDistribution$1.call(DistributionFactory.java:112)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        ... 1 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:90)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.getInstance(Validator.java:179)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.getValidator(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:314)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedInit(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:173)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:186)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1320)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:154)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1032)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1328)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
        ... 19 more
    Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
        at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.setTrustAnchors(PKIXParameters.java:200)
        at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.<init>(PKIXParameters.java:120)
        at java.security.cert.PKIXBuilderParameters.<init>(PKIXBuilderParameters.java:104)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:88)
        ... 31 more
```

Comment: I just recently began receiving the same exception, although with a slightly different cause stack. In the end, my `GradleConnectionException` is caused by a `java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file`. But the top most exception is the connection exception complaining about the Gradle distribution file. I recently upgraded my Gradle version to 2.3. Have you done the same?

Comment: For me, problem was solved by making my wrapper a nightly build of version 2.4. See [here](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-3245).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by updating my wrapper to Nightly build of version 2.4